# Showing $\det(I_E+f)=\sum_{p=0}^{n}\mathrm{tr}(f^p)$ where $f^p:Λ^{p}(E) \to Λ^{p}(E)$ and $f:E\to E$

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors, multilinear-algebra

> $E$ is a vector space with dimension $n$ and $f:E\to E$ is a linear map and for every $p=1,2,3,...$ we have $f^p:Λ^{p}(E) \to Λ^{p}(E)$ which is defined as below
>
> $$(f^p(\alpha))(x_1,x_2,...,x_p)=\alpha(f(x_1),f(x_2),...,f(x_p))$$
> and $f^0=I$ is Identity map

**show that** $$\det(I_E+f)=\sum_{p=0}^{n}\mathrm{tr}(f^p)$$

I have tried to write matrix of $f$ and $f^p$ with respect to a basis of $E$ and corresponding ones to $Λ^{p}(E)$ and it seems simple , but I think maybe it can be solved with some other way.

Comment: What have you tried? BTW, this is purely linear algebra, and multilinear algebra. Differential geometry has nothing to do with this.

Comment: I am going to write my attempt

Comment: You can prove this identity directly, using the matrix of $f$ relative to some basis of $E$ and explicit calculations. Or, if you are working over some real or complex vector space, you could first prove the formula on diagonalisable complex linear mappings, and conclude by density that the formula holds true for all complex linear mappings (and hence for all real linear mappings if you work over $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Yes exactly , I have tried to write matrix of f and $f^p$ and it seems simple , but I think maybe it can be solved with some other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\epsilon \in \bigwedge^n E$.  Then for any $A: E \mapsto E$, the determinant $\det A$ obeys

$$A^n(\epsilon) = (\det A) \epsilon$$

Now do this for $A = I + f$, and let $X = x_1 \wedge x_2 \wedge \ldots \wedge x_n$:

$$\det(I + f) \epsilon(X) =\epsilon [ (I+f)(x_1) \wedge (I+f)(x_2) \wedge \ldots \wedge (I+f)(x_n)]$$

Now, suppose the vectors $x_i$ form an orthogonal set.  We'll get terms like

$$\epsilon(X) + \epsilon[f(x_1) \wedge x_2 \ldots \wedge x_n] + \epsilon[x_1 \wedge f(x_2) \wedge \ldots \wedge x_n] + \ldots$$

Consider the second term.  When the $x_i$ are orthonormal (normality is not required, but done for convenience here), it becomes clear that the only component of $f(x_1)$ that matters is the $x_1$ component of that vector; the other components are annihilated on the wedge.  So this term becomes $\epsilon[(x_1) \cdot f(x_1) X]$.  Carrying this out over all the first-order terms yields $\sum_{i} \epsilon[x_i \cdot f(x_i) X]$.  That is clearly a trace; we're summing the diagonal components of the corresponding matrix.

All the other terms would turn out exactly the same way.

Incidentally, you also prove that $\det f = \mathrm{tr} f^n$ as a result.

Comment: @Muphrid-What's meaning of $\epsilon(X)$?  I do not understand that Why $\det(I + f) \epsilon(X) =\epsilon [ (I+f)(x_1) \wedge (I+f)(x_2) \wedge \ldots \wedge (I+f)(x_n)]$ ? Please explain your solution mathematically completely.

Comment: In this question $\alpha$ is a $p$-form--that is, $E$ might be $V^*$ for some vector space $V$.  Hence, $\epsilon(X)$ should be understood as the action of an $n$-form on $X \in \bigwedge V^n$. I converted the several multilinear arguments in $\epsilon(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$ into an $n$-vector, yielding $\epsilon(x_1 \wedge x_2 \wedge \ldots \wedge x_n)$. These are equivalent--the same concept expressed in two different notations--so I didn't remark on it.  The expression I gave for the determinant follows from that as well as the statement in the question for the definition of $f^p$.